# branching and merging strategies

Tags: tfs, merge, branch

I am looking for information on branching and merging strategies for .net projects. I have been discussing best practice approaches with other developers and would like to read up on the topic.

For example, we have Main/Head which is the main source tree of source code. Release branches are created for branches and merged to main where appropriate. Development branches are created for pieces of work and are merged to and from main. I am looking for guidelines to best practises strategies, do's and dont's etc.

Our source control is TFS2008.

Any links or articles on this topic would be great?

Answer (score 0):

The best place to start is with the [branching guidance](http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/) produced by the ALM Rangers, the latest version is for TFS 2010 but it's applicable to 2008. If you're building software as products then the guidance is very good, if you're building in house software then I'd suggest droping the idea of a service pack branch.